# Finding polynomial from sum and product of zeroes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The question is

Form a quadratic polynomial whose sum of zeroes are $-1/3$ and product of zeroes are, $4$.

I did this,

> $\alpha + \beta = \frac{-b}{a} = \frac{-1}{3}$
>
> $\alpha \cdot \beta = \frac ca = 4$
> Take $a=\operatorname{LCM}(4,1)$
>
> $b = \frac{-1}{3}a = \frac{-4}{3} a$
>
> $c= 4\times4 = 16$
>
> So, $4x^2 - \frac{-4}{3}x + 16$

Is this correct ?
I did it referring to another solution and don't get about the LCM part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LCM does not make sense here.
The polynomial $$ (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$
is zero precisely when $x=\alpha$ or $x=\beta$. Multiply this out and see if $\alpha+\beta$ or $\alpha\beta$ appear somewhere prominently (and can be replaced with $-\frac13$ and $4$).